# How to securely show an auto-generated password in MVC 4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have most of my **MVC 4** web application ready. I have even developed the password auto-generation algorithm. Now I am stuck as to how to show this password to the user.

The controller handling the **Sign Up** process is the one that will generate the password by calling a method from the `PasswordGenerator` class. I want to show this to the user in a message box using some jQuery.

I've tried passing it through `TempData` and `ViewBag` but the password can be seen in the HTML code sent over the internet. Is there anyway to do this securely without showing the password over the internet?

**FYI**, sending an email with the password is not an option. This is a class project, not intended for something of that magnitude.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As the user is accessing your site via the internet, you obviously need to transmit any text that you want to show to him via the internet?

Comment: I get that. Is there any hidden field or encrypted field that can be used for this though?

Comment: What's the threat model here? Are you worried about an attacker intercepting the message in transport, or about an attacker standing behind your user reading it off their screen?

Comment: @IainGalloway, the threat is message interception. Or, judging from how careless people are, leaving their computers unlocked so anyone can access the code while they are away. I'm just trying to be careful.

Comment: you do not ever need to worry about plain text being sent from the server to the client, it is going to be displayed in the HTML anyways.  There only thing here is to worry about a an in the middle attack - meaning someone other than your intended client viewing the text.  Trust me - that is way beyond the scope of the class project you are working on.  That would be in a seperate class entirely

Comment: You really don't have a choice. There is nothing the browser can do to prevent people from being careless about not locking their computer or allowing someone to stare over their shoulder. You can send the password to the user over HTTPS, where it will not be visible to others. Perhaps you can also make some kind of button where the user has to click or touch in order to see the password. But that is about it.

Comment: So basically I cannot do anything better than TempData or ViewBag. Well, sucks to be me, I guess. Thanks a lot guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters, there's nothing special about jQuery, `TempData`, or `ViewBag` that's useful to you here. Anything you send over the internet gets, you know, sent over the internet. If an attacker has control of your user's network, then they can intercept a javascript->WebApi call or an email more-or-less as easily as they can intercept an HTML page.

More generally, you should be aware of the trade-offs between security, usability, and development cost. By-and-large there is no such thing as "secure". There are threats you can mitigate and specific attacks you can and should defend against, but there's also a level of risk you can accept depending on the nature of your service.

So, what can we do in this situation:-

1. The most obvious action to take (and the only one I would truly recommend in your case) is to enable SSL. This secures your transport layer against most snooping with no practical drawbacks. Any time you send sensitive data over the internet, you should use SSL. Some would argue you should use SSL *always*.
2. You can mitigate over-the-shoulder-type snooping by hiding the password using javascript, and having the user perform some action to "uncover" it (such as hovering the mouse pointer over a target, or pressing a button). Beware that some of your users may be inexperienced, disabled, or using a mobile device. If I were assessing you, I would care far more that you were "being careful" about accessibility than about hand-rolling your own security hacks!
3. You can mitigate computer-left-unlocked attacks somewhat by timing out the user's session. You'll see this used frequently with internet banking. Be aware that this also has a usability cost - in particular I would be concerned about timing a user out while they're looking for a pen and a post-it to write down the password you generated for them!

A tangential note:- [Storing passwords properly is hard](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Password_Storage_Cheat_Sheet), and storing passwords improperly can be disastrous. Make sure you're doing it correctly! **At your level of experience, I would strongly advise against rolling your own password storage system unless your assessor has specifically asked you to.** Furthermore, having the server generate passwords for end users to remember is quite controversial. If you haven't been specifically asked for it, you should consider whether it is the right approach and make sure you justify it. For something of this scale, you may want to look into some kind of federated authentication (e.g. "sign in with your google account") instead of handling passwords at all.